# Do I Use the JDate correctly?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

Actually I encounter a problem with usage of JDate.

Joomla has a class JDate for managing dates.
I tested the following code:

```
$date = new JDate('2017-07-28 00:00:00');
$timestamp_jdate = $date->toUnix();
$timestamp = strtotime('2017-07-28 00:00:00');
```

I was expecting that $timestamp_jdate and $timestamp returned the same result but this is the results I obtained:
$timestamp_jdate = 1501200000
$timestamp = 1501192800

Did I do something wrong? How can I fix it?

I saw in the API that the JDate constructor can have a second parameter $tz but it is not well documented so maybe I have to set this parameter?

Any help would be grateful :-)

Answer (score 3):

$tz is the timezone. After setting it to the default system timezone the 2 timestamps match!
By default, the timezone on Joomla is UTC. My system timezone was 'Europe/Berlin'.

Hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 1):

Let Joomla! take care of stuff for you.

```
$date = JFactory::getDate('2017-07-28 00:00:00');
$unixDate = $date->toUnix();
```

Or

```
$date = new JDate(JHtml::date('2017-07-28 00:00:00', 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$unixDate = $date->toUnix();
```

Comment: Actually,the timestamp was given by an xml file (outside of Joomla context) so I needed to compare this timestamp to a date which was in my Joomla database.